# Structural design patterns: (Private class data) Is there a difference between these two examples

Tags: java, design-patterns, encapsulation, design-principles

The following is an example of this pattern from sourcemaking.com:

https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/private_class_data

There are two examples, the crossed out main class and the main class that contains the data class.

My question is simply what is the difference between the following and the given correct implementation at the link:

```
public class MainClass {

    private final <Type> attribute1;
    private final <Type> attribute2;
    private final <Type> attribute3;

    public MainClass(<Type> attribute1, <Type> attribute2, <Type> attribute3 {
        this.attribute1 = attribute1;
        this.attribute2 = attribute2;
        this.attribute3 = attribute3;
    }
}
```

Cheers

Comment: You're missing the generic type definition in your question

Comment: I think the benefits of externalizing data class from business logic becomes more evident with larger classes. This small class doesn't really serves the example.

Comment: Note that pattern is not from the GoF. It looks more like an anti-pattern to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code here is not an example of that pattern. The crossed out model is what not to do.

You need a separate Java object to hold the attributes, and that page lists exactly why the pattern exists - to limit exposure of fields

And since this point

> Main class must initialize data class through the data class's constructor

The data object can be declared as final

Comment: I think OP understood that point, but in his example declared fields as final to make sure they're not modified after. That's his point I think.

Comment: The difference is still that there's a separate object. And that object can act as a façade for other business logic that does not need exposure from the top level class

Comment: The facade angle is interesting, thanks for the responses guys